# Multiple Book Versions

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I imagine this has been asked before, I'm just struggling to find the right answer.

Using Books to create documentation for an open source project. We're covering 3 domains, Users, Developers, and Admins. Easy enough.

Where I am struggling is how to create versions of these books for each software release. Do I just create a new book for every version? 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, etc? Should I be using a taxonomy vocab for the releases? What is a manageable way to handle this?

Comment: Does the content between point releases of your software vary slightly or significantly? Does the content of a version doc change after the software is released? I would create new books for each new release if it's important to steer visitors to a particular version documentation. I'd find a way to duplicate content if there is a lot of it, then edit to add the changes for the new version. The old versions wouldn't change in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation can be done in many different ways using different modules. If you decided to go with Books, then it is really up to you to create new books or taxonomies for new releases. Look at how Drupal's documentations is organized on https://www.drupal.org/documentation.